# SUMIFS across multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I have a formula that works on `WK01` but i cannot get it to work across the other 51 worksheets

`=SUMIFS('WK01'!$H$5:$H$14,'WK01'!$Z$5:$Z$14,H9,'WK01'!$D$5:$D$14,$F$8)`

The worksheet names are held in range `tabs` on the worksheet `varibles` can 'WK01' be changed to look at all worksheets in 'tabs' range?

The formula is located on `Home Page`, `G9`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'"&tabs&"'!$H$5:$H$14"),INDIRECT("'"&tabs&"'!$Z$5:$Z$14"),H9,INDIRECT("'"&tabs&"'!$D$5:$D$14"),$F$8))
```

Use sparsely since it's a heavy **volatile** function!

Comment: Works great, Thanks